# createAsyncThunk and writing reducer login with redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I was reading `createAsyncThunk` documentation, and felt kind of confused with the flow. This is from the docs:

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { userAPI } from './userAPI'

// First, create the thunk
const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/fetchByIdStatus',
  async (userId, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await userAPI.fetchById(userId)
    return response.data
  }
)

// Then, handle actions in your reducers:
const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState: { entities: [], loading: 'idle' },
  reducers: {
    // standard reducer logic, with auto-generated action types per reducer
  },
  extraReducers: {
    // Add reducers for additional action types here, and handle loading state as needed
    [fetchUserById.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      // Add user to the state array
      state.entities.push(action.payload)
    }
  }
})

// Later, dispatch the thunk as needed in the app
dispatch(fetchUserById(123))
```

What do I have to write in the `reducers` and `extraReducers`? Standard reducer logic?

I have this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-montalcini-oks4m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) that I implemented the old redux way. Now, need to implement `redux-toolkit` in it.

Comment: It is literally written in the comment what you need to do there.

Comment: @metalHeadDev do you have a final implementation to look at?

Answer (score 0):

The `reducers` property of `createSlice` allows you to make an action creator function and respond to those actions in one step.  You use `extraReducers` to respond to an action that has already been created elsewhere, like in an async thunk.  The `extraReducer` just responds to an action but does not create an action creator function.

The example is saying that you can have some regular `reducers` in addition to the `extraReducers`.  But I looked at your CodeSandbox and in your case you do not need any other `reducers` because the only actions that you are responding to are the three actions from the async thunk.

Since your `createSlice` isn't going to make any action creators you don't really need to use `createSlice`.  You can use it, but you can also just use [`createReducer`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer).

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { userAPI } from './userAPI'

export const fetchUserFromGithub = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/fetch',
  async (username) => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://api.github.com/users/${username}`
    );
    return response.data
  }
)

const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState: {
    user: null,
    fetchingUser: false,
    fetchingError: null
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchUserFromGithub.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.fetchingUser = true;
      state.fetchingError = null;
    },
    [fetchUserFromGithub.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.fetchingUser = false;
      state.fetchingError = action.error;
    }
    [fetchUserFromGithub.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.fetchingUser = false;
      state.user = action.payload;
    }
  }
})
```